# Image in a full screen div that preserve aspect ratio

Tags: jquery, css, image, html, fullscreen

I try to put a image in a div to be displayed in full screen. I tried in many ways, but i have many problems if the image has more height than width, in those cases, image should be displayed centered and the remaining space with the background color of the container div, I don't want to crop the image

Comment: can we see your code?

Comment: If only put the image with this style 'img {
   width: auto;
   max-height: 100%;
}' this is showed in a correct aspect ratio, but i neef the image in a div and centered.

Answer (score 2):

Use `background-size:contain`. This will prevent cropping and maintain the ratio, while still atemting to fill as much space as possible.

To center use `background-position:center;`

```
div {
  background-image:url('http://static.tumblr.com/purt4nm/BCJmqjvcj/1367698942181.jpg');
}
```

http://jsbin.com/enaxif/1/edit

Comment: thanks but i need the class or id of image, to use javascript

Comment: image preserves ratio on its own and wont crop anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this?

```
<img src="path" height="100%" />
```